# List all programs with install date programmatically

Tags: c#, powershell, wmi, office365

I am trying to get information about all installed software on my PC. I want the same information I see on Add/Remove programs in windows. My problem is that for some programs I don't get an installed date even if Add/Remove programs displays it.

For example: Office 365

In Add/Remove Programs I can see an install date. If I check the default places for uninstall information in the registry I can find office 365 but no install date.

Places I've checked:

- HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
- HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
- HKU\USER-SID-HERE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
- HKU\USER-SID-HERE\Software\Microsoft\Installer\Products
- HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\USER-SID-HERE\Products
- HKLM\Software\Classes\Installer\Products

I tried it with `wmi (SELECT * FROM Win32_Product)`, but I only get entries with names like Office 15 Click-to-Run Entries, no entry with the caption "Office 365" (like in ADd/Remove Programs).

I am out of ideas. Does anyone know how and where Add/Remove programs gets its informations?

My last idea ist just to use the folder creation date of the install location, but I don't think this is a clean solution.
I hope someone can help me out. I dont care if the solution is a script or program.

Answer (score 3):

Powershell:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | select DisplayName, Publisher, InstallDate
```

Comment: My problem is that icant get the Installdate of some software (like Office 365) in Add/Remove programs i can see an installed date. Result of your powershell query: `Microsoft Office 365 - de-de            Microsoft Corporation`

Answer (score 0):

This only works for the msi provider.  Strangely get-package doesn't give the installdate.  Powershell 5.1 only.  The installdate is just a sortable string in the form YYYYMMDD.  Some software has both a programs and an msi entry.

```
$guid = get-package softwarename -provider msi | % fastpackagereference
get-itemproperty hklm:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\$guid installdate |
  select installdate

InstallDate
-----------
20231106
```